Vite module federation with different react versions
I'm getting this error once trying to import remote app into the host using vite module federation plugin:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at react_production_min.useState

These are my config files:
Remote:
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: 'supportClients',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './App': './src/App',
      },
      shared: {
        react: { requiredVersion: '^18.3.1' },
        'react-dom': { requiredVersion: '^18.3.1' },
      },
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: 'esnext',
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
});

Host:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: 'hostApp',
            remotes: {
                supportClients: 'http://localhost:8081/assets/remoteEntry.js',
            }
        })
    ],
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: "esnext",
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
})

The idea is to have 2 different versions of react, any idea what's going on?
